# Como alinear divs en la parte superior? html - css

Tags: html, css, scss

Tengo este slider que está funcionando con Tiny slider js. Cada `slide` tiene un encabezado (div rosa) y el contenido dentro de otro div (div verde).
Cómo puedo alinear los divs verde en la parte superior cuando alguno de los encabezados tiene más texto que los demás?

Los div rosa deben crecer pero hacia arriba y no hacia abajo para que los div verde queden alineados en la parte superior.

Ayuda por favor!!!

```js
    const tabsSlider = document.querySelectorAll('.js-slider');
    tabsSlider.forEach(slider => {

        const tnsSlider = tns({
            container: slider,
            mouseDrag: true,
            nav: false,
            controls: false,
            items: 2,
            loop: false,
            slideBy: 2,
            mode: "carousel",
            swipeAngle: false,
            edgePadding: 30,
            speed: 400,
        });
    });
```

```css
.slider-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.slide {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.slide-heading {
  background-color: pink;
}

.slide-heading p,
.slide-heading h4{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.slide-content {
  border: 1px solid greenyellow;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.4/min/tiny-slider.js"></script>
<div class="slider-wrapper js-slider">
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="slide-box">
            <div class="slide-heading">
                <h4 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>                    
                <p  class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores!</p>
            </div><!--/.slide-heading-->
            <div class="slide-content">
                <div class="content">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore necessitatibus, aperiam quasi voluptates assumenda neque fugiat. Enim ipsa quos facere, similique, iste placeat aperiam veniam, numquam qui neque illum odio!</p>
                </div><!--/.description-->
            </div><!--/.slide-content-->
        </div><!--/.slide-box-->
    </div><!--/.slide-->
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="slide-box">
            <div class="slide-heading">
                <h4 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>                    
                <p  class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores!</p>
            </div><!--/.slide-heading-->
            <div class="slide-content">
                <div class="content">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore necessitatibus, aperiam quasi voluptates assumenda neque fugiat. Enim ipsa quos facere, similique, iste placeat aperiam veniam, numquam qui neque illum odio!</p>
                </div><!--/.description-->
            </div><!--/.slide-content-->
        </div><!--/.slide-box-->
    </div><!--/.slide-->
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="slide-box">
            <div class="slide-heading">
                <h4 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>                    
                <p  class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores!</p>
            </div><!--/.slide-heading-->
            <div class="slide-content">
                <div class="content">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore necessitatibus, aperiam quasi voluptates assumenda neque fugiat. Enim ipsa quos facere, similique, iste placeat aperiam veniam, numquam qui neque illum odio!</p>
                </div><!--/.description-->
            </div><!--/.slide-content-->
        </div><!--/.slide-box-->
    </div><!--/.slide-->
</div><!--/.slider-wrapper-->
```

Comment: Solo usando flex no vas a poder alinear de esa manera los divs con tu estructura actual, puesto que no tienen un acenstro común. Con flex puedes hacer que los hijos de un determinado padre crezcan/se estiren/encojan todos en la misma proporción, pero al tener padres completamente diferentes, es distinto. No sé si lo que buscas se puede hacer solo con css, tal vez usando un grid... pero no se me da nada bien usar grid, así que ni idea :) De todas maneras, como puede "crecer hacia arriba" si el html se escribe hacia abajo? Me dejas patidifunto.

Comment: Te escribo cómo entendí tu pregunta, y aclarame si la entendí bien (porque en verdad es confusa): al decir _los div rosa deben crecer pero hacia arriba y no hacia abajo para que los div verde queden alineados en la parte superior_, te referís a que los divs rosas pueden tener tamaño dinámico, siempre y cuando se alineen en la parte inferior (por lo tanto, los divs verdes también quedarán alineados en la parte superior), ¿es así? ¿O los divs rosas pueden tener un espaciado entre cada una de ellas con su respectivo div verde, con tal de que los divs verdes queden alineados en la parte superior?

Comment: @padaleiana Sí, lo que necesito es como lo que entendiste de primero: "Que los divs rosas pueden tener tamaño dinámico, siempre y cuando se alineen en la parte inferior (por lo tanto, los divs verdes también quedarán alineados en la parte superior)"